# PHP return vs echo

Tags: php, string, return, wordpress-theming, echo

I have a series of functions that is suppose to, in the end create a form. they reside in a class such as the following example:

```
class ExampleForm{
    protected $_html = '';

    protected $_element;

    public function __construct($element){
        $this->_element = $element;   

    protected function _open_form(){
       echo $this->_html .= '<form>';
    }

    public function create_form(){
       $this->_open_form()
       $this->_html .= $this->_element;
       echo "some content";
       $this->_close_form()
    }

    protected function _close_form(){
        echo $this->_html .= '</form>'
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->_html;
}
```

Instantiated as:

```
$element = 'some element';
new ExampleForm($element);
```

A more comprehensive example can be seen on [Github on line 86](https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Framework/blob/dev1.2/AisisCore/Form/Form.php)
this content gets echoed out, How ever its echoed out side the form.

If you want to see a live action demo of this [Then you'll deff wan't me.](http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/uncategorized/more-content-2) at the end of the day if you inspect the form on the web page, you'll see above the form opening tag two hidden fields that need to be **inside the form tags**.

Now one would think this would create a form such as:

```
<form>
    element
    some conent
</form>
```

How ever, what I get is:

```
some content
<form>
    element
</form>
```

So can some one tell me, based on what I have above why I am getting my "some content" echoed out side the form tag even though I have echoed the opening form tag?

even if I do not echo the opening form tag the "some content" still appears out side the opening form tag.

Comment: now add the code calling the class and its methods

Comment: Please post all of the code you are using to output this. You need to show us how/where the functions inside the class are being called.

Comment: How you are instantiating your class and calling those functions? Please provide code.

Comment: I have added examples. Because I cannot post more then two links I hope what I gave was enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return will simply return the variable without echoing it, where as echo will echo it out when it is called. So if you return a variable and then echo something. So in your function create_form(), instead of `echo "some content";` just do `$this->_html .= "some content";`

Answer (score 3):

echo performs output immediately, e.g.

```
function bar() {
   echo 'bar';
}

bar();
echo 'foo';
```

gives `barfoo` as the output. But if you had

```
function bar() {
    return 'bar';
}

$baz = bar();
echo 'foo';
echo $baz;
```

you'll get `foobar`

Comment: So what should I do in my case to make sure that "some content" is staying inside the tags?